# Spring MVC Portlet DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Choosing Controller Class

Tags: spring-mvc, portlet

I am trying to use [DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/portlet/mvc/annotation/DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.html) for annotated Controllers in Spring **Portlet MVC.**

My portlet works with one controller. But I am not able to understand as to how `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` is able to determine which Controller to choose among many controllers in the same package.

This [link](http://www.andypemberton.com/spring/annotation-based-spring-portlet-mvc-lifecycle/) says that it searches for best matching Controller. But I could not understand the rules to determine the best matching controller.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

Beware of the bug in Spring 3.1.2. I explained some portion of what you asked in [Is this a Bug in Spring 3.1.2 ( specifically Spring Portlet MVC's )?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11996771/is-this-a-bug-in-spring-3-1-2-specifically-spring-portlet-mvcs)

I also logged at bug https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9697 .

Hope you find it useful.