# DispatcherPortlet is not collecting data about controllers

Tags: spring-mvc, liferay, requestdispatcher

i have developed an easy portlet in Liferay. Ive used the Spring MVC template. 
On my local development (LF 6.2 GA2) the dispatching between "sites" is working. After deployment on the server LF (LF 6.2 GA1) the dispatcher is not dispatching any more to some of the links. LF is forwaring to the "home" page defined in

```
<portlet-class>org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet</portlet-class>    
        <init-param>
            <name>view-template</name>
            <value>/jsp/home.jsp</value>
        </init-param>
```

It seems like the dispatcher was not collection all data from all controllers. 
Im using the portlet:renderURL method.

And in the controller classes im using the @RenderMapping, @ActionMapping or @ResourceMapping.

My Question: Does anybody have some idea, whats here going on? Is there any possibility to check, whether the dispatcher on the server LF has found all controllers and mapping methods? Is there something what could i do as next?

Thanx you all!

Comment: Would you elaborate statement ' After deployment on the server LF (LF 6.2 GA1) the dispatcher is not dispatching any more to some of the links' with more detail?

Comment: Well, this is my opinion, because after clicking on the link to the object im getting the home page again. There is no error in the log (such if something was wrong like there is no controller mapping to the parameter etc.). So there has to be something strange happing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same problem was here [Is this a Bug in Spring 3.1.2 ( specifically Spring Portlet MVC's )?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11996771/is-this-a-bug-in-spring-3-1-2-specifically-spring-portlet-mvcs/28203679#28203679) .

The solution is to use the spring framework version 3.1.4 and more.